# Overlapping ripples on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm seeing this odd things on Lollipop.  The ripple effect on the list view seems to have two parts which causes this partial overlapping ripple to appear.  Video can be seen [here](https://plus.google.com/+BryanLogan/posts/RQM7GJtBRwJ).

I've set the background of my TextView and CheckedTextView to @color/transparent, but it's still there.  I also set the backgrounds to just solid colors, and they don't even line up where that square is.  The square is always in the same spot, regardless of the name length.

Other goofiness is that if I do a screen recording, it won't show up.  Slow down animation by 10x, it won't show up.

The ListView has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:paddingTop="4dp"
              android:paddingBottom="4dp"
              android:paddingLeft="4dp"
              android:minHeight="56dp"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.LollipopTheme.Dark">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/agent_directory_row_icon"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_agent_photo"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:id="@+id/check"
                     android:textColor="@color/white"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                     android:visibility="gone"
                     android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"/>

    <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/agent_directory_row_name"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text=""
                 android:textSize="24sp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:maxLines="1"
                 android:ellipsize="end"
                 android:gravity="left"
                 android:textColor="#FF3e3e3e"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: It's occurring on my One Plus One with CM12S. I went and tested on a Nexus 4 and Nexus 7. It does not occur there.

Unfortunately, I don't have any more Lollipop test devices. I'd really like to verify on another non-Nexus device.

Maybe this is Cyanogenmod specific.

Comment: Have you tried setting clickable attribute to false for all views, if you want to click the whole row as one.? I am not sure if that is ok with you.

Comment: @dora I tried this and it has no effect.

Comment: How are you setting the background to transparent? From XML? If so, please show XML that includes this.

Comment: @alanv I used android:background="@color/transparent" in the XML, but it made no difference. See my update.  I'm wondering if this isn't Cyanogenmod specific.